# Does MetaMask provide access to acount's keystore file?

Tags: accounts, metamask, keystore, keymanagement

I am looking for my account's keystore file. I know usually this is only available through geth.

MetaMask already provides the private key, but I'm not looking for the the private key, I'm looking for keystore UTC file.

Does MetaMask provide keystore access? If so where is its location?

Comment: No, MetaMask doesn't export that format. Can you explain why you want it in that format? If it's for backup, you can save the seed phrase instead. If it's to import in another tool, most will accept the private key directly.

Comment: @smarks I'm testing out various approaches for user transactions. Truffle-wallet-provider allows you to build out a provider using the keystore file and password. I would like to instruct a user to input a keystore value into a UI so that they can use the truffle-wallet-provider. More experimental then anything.

Comment: If you have `geth` installed, just import the private key there, enter a password, and grab the resulting JSON file. You could also use [`keythereum`](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum).